# Change Windows 7 Sort by Modification Date default to ascending

Tags: windows-7, windows

Change Windows 7 Sort by Modification Date default to ascending, When selecting Sort Option by modification date, it now defaults to descending. Hw does one change the default to ascending (like in XP and prior)?

Answer (score 0):

well in win 7 and 8 / 8.1 if you click in the `date` header of the window (it's showed in `list view` the other views doesn't shows it) the sorting will be arranged and the header will show a small `triangle arrow` indicating if its arranged descending or ascending